# My number checker function isn't working, why?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

```
function numbCheck() {
// Declaring variables
            var toCheck = prompt("Enter a string!");
            var numbCount = 0;
            // For loop to cycle through toCheck and look for numbers
            for (i = 0; i <= toCheck.length; i++) {
                if (toCheck.charCodeAt(i) <= "9" && toCheck.charCodeAt(i) >= "0") {
                    numbCount++;
                }
            }
            // If a number is found numbCount should be > 0 and the alert will go off
            if (numbCount > 0) {
                alert("You can't have a number in your name!");
            }
        }
        numbCheck();
```

I think the problem lies with the <= "9" bit in the for loop, but I could be totally wrong. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using numbers as strings? Maybe you want: `if (toCheck.charCodeAt(i) <= 9 && toCheck.charCodeAt(i) >= 0) {` ?

Comment: @PM77-1 This is JavaScript, not C, C++, etc. Single-quotes and double-quotes are both strings.

Comment: Why not use a regex: `if (toCheck.match(/\d/) !== null) {..`

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you're seeing?  Are you getting an error message?  Or just incorrect results?  If incorrect results, what is incorrect about them?

Answer (score 1):

[Working JsBin](https://jsbin.com/zapiqi/1/edit?js,console)

It's not the '<= "9"'

You need to access the indexes in `toCheck` like so: 
`toCheck[i]`:

```
function numbCheck() {
// Declaring variables
            var toCheck = prompt("Enter a string!");
            var numbCount = 0;
            // For loop to cycle through toCheck and look for numbers
            for (i = 0; i <= toCheck.length; i++) {
                if (toCheck[i] <= "9" && toCheck[i] >= "0") {
                    numbCount++;
                }
            }
            // If a number is found numbCount should be > 0 and the alert will go off
            if (numbCount > 0) {
                alert("You can't have a number in your name!");
            }
        }
        numbCheck();
```

Now, as the other commenters have mentioned, you are trying to see if one number is bigger than another, but you are comparing strings:

Lets say we pass 'asdf5'. You then isolate '5' in the loop and compare it with another string: `'5' <= '9'`, while it works here, you should always compare the same types.

in JS `'9' == 9` is `true` while `'9' === 9` is `false`.

Get in the habit of thinking about what types you are dealing with, it isn't causing problems here, but it will down the road!

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!

Comment: no prob! please keep in mind the above, welcome to SO! - if the answer is to your liking you can select it as the correct answer, and we can close the question

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to do

```
if (toCheck.charCodeAt(i) <= "9".charCodeAt(0) && toCheck.charCodeAt(i) >= "0".charCodeAt(0)) {
```

and, you can use RegExp

```
/[0-9]/.test(toCheck)
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/guvuxukafa/edit?js,console)

Try this one!

```
function numbCheck() {
// Declaring variables
            var toCheck = prompt("Enter a string!");
            var numbCount = 0;
            // For loop to cycle through toCheck and look for numbers
            for (i = 0; i <= toCheck.length; i++) {
              console.log(toCheck.charCodeAt(i));
                if (toCheck.charCodeAt(i) <= "9".charCodeAt(0) && toCheck.charCodeAt(i) >= "0".charCodeAt(0)) {
                    numbCount++;
                }
            }
            // If a number is found numbCount should be > 0 and the alert will go off
            if (numbCount > 0) {
                alert("You can't have a number in your name!");
            }
        }
        numbCheck();
```

if you want Compare with UNICODE,you have to change UNICODE "0"and"9" too.

Comment: sorry, my link is wrong. [link](https://jsbin.com/guvuxukafa/edit?js,console) checkthis @Omarjmh